# Bing image search api not working

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

Hi I am trying to use the Bing image search services and following the documentation from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/quickstarts/csharp

When I run my code debugging it on the BingImageSearch method with the line -

`HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;`

It returns a 401 error. It is an authorization error.
I am using this for the api calls:

```
const string uriBase = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search";
    const string accessKey = "********";
```

My accessKey is correct already checked on azure but I still get the 401 error.
This is the rest of the code for the request:

```
// Construct the URI of the search request
        var uriQuery = uriBase + "?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("Puppies");
        // Perform the Web request and get the response
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriQuery);
        request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = accessKey;
```

What am I missing here? Is it something on the url?

Comment: Do you also have an API for the same service [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services) under the same account as you do in Azure? If so, I wonder if they conflict with each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already figured it out. On the azure resource for the bing api, under the pricing tier options if your pricing tier does not include the images search it won't work. I had it set for web and video the S5 standard pricing so changed it to the web and images S3 standard and that solved it.

Comment: Since you found the answer to your question, please mark your answer as accepted answer. This will help people in the community who have similar question.